# Email design: resizing text for mobile removes mobile image swap

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize, font-size

I'm designing an email campaign template for a client and running into an issue. Trying to set my mobile styles to font-size:100% important!; but there seems to be a sizing issue here. The only things affected are #requiredFooterText td, leadline td, #full td, and #paragraphText. It simply doesn't resize for mobile and I need it to 14px. Picture 1 is what I have and Picture 2 is what I want.

Picture 1 - [image: http://i1145.photobucket.com/albums/o520/cdcmuz/ScreenShot2015-01-15at43010AM.png]

Picture 2 - [image: http://s1145.photobucket.com/user/cdcmuz/media/ScreenShot2015-01-15at43042AM.png.html]

I've tried to force the the font-size out of percentages as well to 24 px instead of 14px. However, it cuts out mobile hero and footer image in the process.

Hopefully I've explained myself well enough. Code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<style data="noinline">

.appleLink a,
.appleLink {
 color:#777777 !important; 
 text-decoration:none !important;
}

.appleLinkGray a,
.appleLinkGray {
 color:#777777 !important; 
 text-decoration:none !important;
}

.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}

.aBn {
   border-bottom: 0;
}

div #mainWrapper {width:100% !important; 
 table-layout:fixed !important;
}

body {
 margin:0; !important
 padding:0; !important
}

/* MOBILE STYLES */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 
   body[yahoo=yes] {
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding: 0 !important;
   } 
 
   table[class=mobileHide], 
 td[class=mobileHide],
 span[class=mobileHide] {
    display: none !important;
 }
  
   div[class=mobileShow] {
  display: block !important; 
  max-height: none !important;
 }
   
 table[class=mobileShow] {
  display: table !important; 
  max-height: none !important;
 }
 
   a[class=mobileShow] {
  display: inline !important; 
  max-height: none !important;
 }
 
   img[class=mobileShow] {
  display: block !important; 
  max-height: none !important;
 }

 table[id=mainWrapper],
 table[id=main],
 table[id=headerWrapper],
 table[id=leadlineWrapper],
 table[id=heroMobile],
 table[id=messageWrapper],
 table[id=footerMobile]
 div[id=logo] {
  margin:0 auto !important;
  width:100% !important; 
 }

 table[id=heroMobile] img
 table[id=footerMobile] img {
  display: block !important; 
  height:auto !important;
  width:100% !important;
 }

 td[id=requiredFooterText]
 td[id=leadline]
 div[id=paragraphText] {
  font-size:100% !important;
 }
 
 td[id=full] {
     display:block;
     width:100%;
  font-size:100% !important;
 }

 
 img[class=icon] {
     width:180px;
  height:160px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
   }
}

/* end MOBILE STYLES*/

</style>

<style>

/* DESKTOP STYLES */
.appleLink a,
.appleLink {
 color:#555555 !important; 
 text-decoration:none !important;
}

.appleLinkGray a,
.appleLinkGray {
 color:#555555 !important; 
 text-decoration:none !important;
}

.mobileShow,
.mobileShow img {
 display: none !important; 
 max-height: 0; 
}

img {
 display:block; 
 border:0;
}
 
p {
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 display:inline;
}

table {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

table td {
 border-collapse:collapse;
}

#paragraphText {
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}


#mainWrapper {
 background: #dadada;
}

#main {
 background: #ffffff;
}

#leadlineWrapper {
 background: #333333;
}

#leadline {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 padding-bottom: 14px;
 padding-top: 15px; 
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

#messageBody {
 padding:20px;
}

#messageBody a {
 color: #d46128;
}

#bulletlist td {
 vertical-align:top;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

#logo {
 background-color:#333333;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:600px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

#requiredFooterText {
 color: #555555;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
}
/* end DESKTOP STYLES*/

</style>

</head>

<body yahoo="yes" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; margin: 0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#dadada">
<table id="mainWrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
 <table id="headerWrapper" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="leadlineWrapper" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
     <tr>
                  <td class="ec_item" id="leadline">Get a premier education on Florida's Gulf Coast.</td>
                </tr>
           </table><!-- /#leadlineWrapper -->
         </td>
    </tr>
 </table><!-- /#headerWrapper -->
 <table id="main" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td class="ec_item" id="heroWrapper">
              <table class="mobileHide" id="heroDesktop" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                 <tr>
                     <td style="text-transform: none;">
                         <a href="cta" target="_blank">
                              <img src="" width="600" height="419" border="0" style="color: #262626; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" alt="Confirm Your Info »" />
                            </a>
                         </td>
       </tr>
                 </table>
                 <!-- /#heroDesktop -->
                 <div class="mobileShow">  
              <table class="mobileShow" id="heroMobile" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                     <tr>
                         <td style="text-transform: none;">
                           <a class="mobileShow" href="cta" target="_blank">
                               <img class="mobileShow" src="" width="320" height="226" border="0" style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" alt="Confirm Your Info »" />
                                </a>
                          </td>
        </tr>
                    </table><!-- /#heroMobile -->
                </div>
             </td>
           </tr><!-- /hero -->
           <tr>
            <td id="messageContainer">
              <table id="messageWrapper" width="590" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                   <tr>
                      <td style="text-transform: none;" id="messageBody">
                             <div class="ec_item" id="paragraphText">
                                 <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                              {First_name},<br /><br />

         When you step onto the <strong>Blank</strong> campus, you know you've arrived somewhere special. In fact, we're one of only 40 schools featured in the book <em>Colleges That Change Lives</em>.
                                    <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                              <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                            </div>
                          
                            
                          <table dir="rtl" id="bulletlist" width="100%">
          <tr>
                                 
            <td width="98%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
          <p><strong>188 acres of waterfront campus</strong> give you unlimited access to the living laboratory of the Gulf of Mexico. We offer an exhilarating academic experience and constantly strive toward inspiring you to THINK<strong>OUT</strong>SIDE.</p>
            </td>
            <td width="1%" id="full"><img src="" /></td>
                                    <td width="1%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
               <p><img src="" width="90" height="80" style="margin:0 auto;" class="icon" /></p>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- /bullet1 -->
                                <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="15"></td>
                                </tr><!-- /spacing -->
                                <tr>
            <td width="98%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
          <p><strong>40 majors and 45 minors</strong> allow you to pursue a range of interests. You can even self-design your own major.</p>
                      
            </td>
            <td width="1%" id="full"><img src="" /></td>
                                    <td width="1%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
               <p><img src="" width="90" height="80" style="margin:0 auto;" class="icon" /></p>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- /bullet2 -->
                                <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="15"></td>
                                </tr><!-- /spacing -->
                                <tr>
            <td width="98%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
          <p><strong>96 percent of students</strong> receive some sort of financial aid, and individual merit scholarships of up to $19,000 are available.</p>
                      
            </td>
            <td width="1%" dir="ltr" id="full"><img src="" /></td>
                                    <td width="1%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
               <p><img src="" width="90" height="80" style="margin:0 auto;" class="icon" /></p>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- /bullet3 -->
                                 <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="15" class="ec_item"></td>
                                </tr><!-- /spacing -->
                                <tr>
            <td width="98%" dir="ltr" id="full" class="ec_item">
          <p><strong>Autumn Term</strong> is an immersive three-week experience led by an expert faculty mentor. Opening with the Ceremony of Lights, your first academic course is a special opportunity to transition to college-level learning while becoming a strong member of the community.</p>
                      
            </td>
            <td width="1%" id="full" class="ec_item"><img src="" /></td>
                                    <td width="1%" dir="ltr" class="ec_item" id="full">
               <p><img src="" width="90" height="80" style="margin:0 auto;" class="icon" /></p>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- /bullet4 -->  
       </table>
                            
                            <div class="ec_item" id="paragraphText"> 
                            <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                            <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                             <strong><u><a href="cta">Confirm your information</a></u></strong> to find out more ways encourages you to THINK<strong>OUT</strong>SIDE.
                            </div>
                            
                            <div width="100%" height="15"><img src="" /></div>
                            
                         </td><!-- /#messageBody -->  
                       </tr>        
              </table><!-- /#messageWrapper -->
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="ec_item" id="footerContainer">
             <table class="mobileHide" id="footerDesktop" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                 <tr>
                     <td style="text-transform: none;">
                         <a href="cta" target="_blank">
                              <img src="" width="600" height="155" border="0" style="color: #262626; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" alt="Confirm Your Info »" />
                            </a>
                         </td>
       </tr>
                 </table>
                 <!-- /#footerDesktop -->
                 <div class="mobileShow">  
              <table class="mobileShow" id="footerMobile" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                     <tr>
                         <td style="text-transform: none;">
                           <a class="mobileShow" href="cta" target="_blank">
                               <img class="mobileShow" src="" width="320" height="144" border="0" style="color: #9c3022; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" alt="Confirm Your Info »" />
                                </a>
                          </td>
        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- /#footerMobile -->
                </div>
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
             <div class="ec_item" id="logo" align="center">
                 <a href="">
                    <img height="49" width="160" style="margin:20px;" src="" style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
           </tr>           
     </tbody>
    </table><!-- /#main -->
 <table id="requiredFooter" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td id="requiredFooterText">
              This message was sent to <a href="mailto:%7BEMAIL%7D" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333;">{EMAIL}</span></a> by <a href="mailto:%7BFROM_EMAIL%7D" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333;">{FROM_EMAIL}</span></a>.<br /><br />
           
              =


              We received your contact information from {CONTACT_SOURCE}.<br /><a href="%7BUnsubscribeURL%7D" target="_blank" style="color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333;">Unsubscribe</span></a> from future email communications from Office of Admission.<br /><br /><br />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table><!-- /#requiredFooter -->
</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- /#mainWrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about css media queries? 
As a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries and
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: The stylesheet in effect is within a media query of 480.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have 2 style in your header.

When it is to an email template, I would advise you to make everything inline style and the things that need to be different on the phone must be in header `@media`, with a `!important` on. as shown in the example.

Hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<style>
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .paragraphText p {
        font-size: 24px !important;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>                            
    <div class="paragraphText">    
        <p style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5;"> Confirm your information</p>
    </div>                                       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even when the styles are added inline, and I force the font-size:24px !important;, the header and footer disappear on iPhone 4s and 5. Normally I'd let one client slide. But seeing as Apple iPhone Mail is about 25% of the consumer email client and iPhone 5 is 27% of that, I can't ignore it. Sadface. Thank you though!